# Simplify Boolean logic to use less operators

Tags: javascript, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

Is there a way to simplify the below logic to use less than **5** operators `(&& / ||)`
without creating new variables?

```
var foo = (A || B) && C && [(A && D) || (B && E)]
```

Comment: what is the bracket `[]` doing?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `[]` means `()`, then you could drop some parenthesis, because of the [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) of `&&` (6) over `||` (5).

```
var foo = (A || B) && C && (A && D || B && E);
```

Then you could drop the first part, because of the condition in the last part,

```
var foo = (A || B) && C && (A && D || B && E);
//         ^    ^           ^         ^
```

because not only `A` has to be `true` as well as `D` or `B` has to be `true` and `E` as well.

```
var foo = C && (A && D || B && E);
```